# Is there a way to set up PCPs without the user having a login?

Tags: personal-campaign-pages, user-account

As the question suggests we are aiming to use PCPs for an event of ours but would rather not have user logins enabled as we don't need them for anything else. Unfortunately all the text on the PCP set up pages tells users they can change things after and login etc, is there an easy way to change these so the users know when they finish its fixed and they will have to contact us for a change as this seems easier than setting up user account sign up just for this one use?

Alternatively if somebody can give me some quick pointers to set it up so the users can sign up for accounts while creating PCPs I'd be happy with that?

I've already spent a few hours searching on this subject so hope I haven't missed something obvious and I'm not wasting everybody's time, really hope somebody can help and thank you in advance!

Sam

Comment: if i am not wrong are you trying to create a PCP along with member sign up

Comment: That would certainly be one of the options yes, its not my favoured way of doing it (I'd rather they just had a link in the confirmation email with auth tokens to get them into it) but getting user account setup along with the PCP set up would at least mean it could go live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this issue before - and found it easiest to go with allowing user registration.  I agree it'd be better if this wasn't necessary, but haven't found anyone willing to fund that improvement.

You haven't specified your CiviCRM version or CMS, which makes it a little more difficult to answer, but the general approach is to create a profile that you intend to use for PCP signup, go into Advanced Settings for that profile, and enable user registration there.  This will enable signup directly on the PCP page.

Note that if you're using Drupal, and you've disabled user registration altogether within Drupal, the user registration block won't appear on the profile.  I assume it's the same for Joomla/WP.

However, since you're enabling user registration, that also means that the default user registration page will also be enabled.  I like to use theming to break the normal user registration page - that will drastically cut down on the number of spam user registrations you'll see.

Comment: Thank you so much Jon, I agree going with user registration turned out to be the easiest way, and you are correct that WP also requires anonymous user account creation turned on. Thank you for taking the time to help, simple to find and do once you know where it is!